# Node value from form state

Tags: 8, forms, entities

I have a node which I want to update from a form states values. I can set each value individually like:

```
$node->set("foo", "bar");
```

Is there a way to mass assign the values instead of setting each individually?

Comment: You can chan the methods or you can simply use the toArray() method, alter values and then call Node::create(). But you would have to properly destroy that original node object I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create an array of name/value pairs and then a simple foreach loop to set them all. Or you can pass it to Node::create() if it is a new node.

There is no setMultiple() or similar API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
```